# how edit the error file and remove stdout in COLAB

Tags: python

When I attempted to add a new feature to my project, I decided to use Buildozer to build it. However, things did not go as smoothly as I had hoped. I encountered an error, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stdout'", which was traced back to the build file of python-for-android that had been installed automatically via Buildozer. This was a frustrating experience for me because now I can no longer build anything at all, not even on Google Colab. I had hoped to use this platform to continue developing my project, but the error I encountered has left me unable to do so. I am now searching for a solution to this issue, but so far I have been unsuccessful in finding one. I am determined to resolve this issue so that I can get back to building my project and adding new features to it. from : avdmanager('list', 'target').stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n'). to : avdmanager('list', 'target').split('\n')

Tried to build my project with Buildozer, but an error appeared when running "buildozer android -v debug". Removing new requirements and permissions did not resolve the issue. Tried building with p4a master and develop branches but with no luck. Looking for a solution to this error to continue development.

Comment: This reads more like a note in your journal. If you have a question it'll need more technical detail.

Comment: from : avdmanager('list', 'target').stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n'). to : avdmanager('list', 'target').split('\n') @tadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I was able to fix it by adding p4a.branch = develop to the buildozer.spec file.

https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#AttributeError-str-object-has-no-attribute-stdout

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot, could you tell me what p4a.branch is? And taking the opportunity, would you know which version of numpy runs better with COLAB? @Max C